NavThroughPoses with a rolling GlobalCostmap
ROS Version: Humble
Setup:

Sensors: RTK-GPS(with fused IMU and Camera) and LiDAR
Localization: GPS based localization and No AMCL(LiDAR based Localization)
Costmaps: Both Global(50x50) and Local(30x30) Costmaps are rolling, Costmaps are large enough to have the subsequent waypoints inside the Map.

Requirement:

I am developing an autonomous farming vehicle using Nav2 Stack for Apple Orchards. I have a set of GPS waypoints(planned path) through which the vehicle should move to reach the Goal.
Currently I am using waypointFollower with "wait_at_waypoint: False", so i expected that the vehicle should move till the Goal without stopping but it stops at every waypoint for around 15 seconds. But in Simulation it was smooth and there was no stopping.
Other possibility is using NavThroughPoses where the vehicle has a cpmplete path and the vehicle moves without stopping at every pose, but the farm is large and setting a large global costmap make the Process Computaionally heavy.

Possible Solution:
Is there a possibility to use the NavThroughPoses with a rolling Costmap. This way the Goal is updated with the moving vehicle till the Final-Goal Pose and there is no need to have a large Global Costmap such that the Final-Goal Pose is always on the Costmap.
I am also open to other ideas as possible Solutions.

Waypoints Follower is using a navigate_to_pose [1] for each waypoint so this is different that NavigateThoughGoals which is designed for your task.
It's possible to have a rolling goal in proximity of your robot. You need just a one custom BT plugin for that.
You could create a behavior tree action plugin for truncating goals. Similar to the existing "Truncate Path" plugin. It would allow later to compute the path from given goals for less amount of goals (for example up to 2 meters in front of the robot). Adding that kind of plugin to that exemplary BT tree [2] could be a solution.
[1]     https://github.com/ros-navigation/navigation2/blob/44a69ccde93514ed1a962b7f18cb101ec671d93a/nav2_waypoint_follower/src/waypoint_follower.cpp#L74
[2] https://github.com/ros-navigation/navigation2/blob/main/nav2_bt_navigator/behavior_trees/navigate_through_poses_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml

Thank you very much for the answer. I found that my simulation (in Unity) was at fault leading to the false assumption that the vehicle can move with continuity from one waypoint to another.
I am currently working on my custom BT plugin, when its done I will update..
